# Angular Custom Control: change event isn't triggered in reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular2-changedetection

This was working fine for some time until I found out it wasn't. The issue I face is the following.

I have an abstract value accessor class which is being extended by multiple custom form controls. It looks like this:

```
@Directive()
export abstract class AbstractInputComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() public isReadOnly = false;

  protected innerValue: unknown = null;
  public registerOnChange(fn: any) { this.propagateChange = fn; }
  public registerOnTouched(fn: any) { this.propagateTouch = fn; }
  public propagateChange = (_: any) => { };
  public propagateTouch = (_: any) => { };

  public ngOnChanges(): void {
    if ( this.isReadOnly ) {
        this.propagateChange(this.value);
    }
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  public get value(): any {
    return this.innerValue;
  };

  @Input() public set value(value: any) {
    if ( value !== undefined ) {
        this.writeValue(value);
        this.propagateChange(this.innerValue);
        this.propagateTouch(true);
    }
  }

  public writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (value !== this.innerValue) {
        this.innerValue = this.normalize(value);
    }
  }
}
```

One of the custom controls looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ultim-checkbox',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    templateUrl: './checkbox-input.component.html',
    providers: [
        {
          provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
          useExisting: forwardRef( ()=> CheckboxInputComponent ),
          multi: true
        },
        {
          provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
          useExisting: forwardRef( ()=> CheckboxInputComponent ),
          multi: true
        }
      ]
})
export class CheckboxInputComponent extends AbstractInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator  {
   constructor ( protected cdr: ChangeDetectorRef ) {
       super(cdr);
   }
}
```

So, then in the big parent template I have this kind of markup:

```
<ultim-checkbox formControlName="isAdmin"
    (change)="setAdmin()"></ultim-checkbox>
```

And `setAdmin()` method never gets called. Any ideas why?

Angular 11
Typescript 5.1.6

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in how you're binding the `(change)` event in the parent template. Since you're using Angular's reactive forms with `formControlName`, the correct event to listen for changes is the `(ngModelChange)` event, not the standard `(change)` event.

Here's how you should modify the parent template:

```
<ultim-checkbox formControlName="isAdmin" (ngModelChange)="setAdmin()"></ultim-checkbox>
```

Comment: You can use also the event `(input)`. Be carefull, (ngModelChange)="yourFunction($event)" the "$event" is the "value", (input)="yourFunction($event)" the "$event" is the "HTML Input element",

Comment: Correct me here :  : Using (input) to capture input events and accessing the input element directly may lead to uncontrolled inputs or unexpected behavior if not handled properly. If you directly access the input element's value and update it, it could cause issues with Angular's change detection and may not work as expected when used with reactive forms or Angular's template-driven forms

Comment: In Angular we need pay attention if you change the "value" of an input using javaScript (using, e.g. document.getElementByIf('myInput').value="fool"), not change the "variable" nor the FormControl. I imagine the advise is related to this, if you use the "event" only to execute a function there's no problem always use well (e.g. really it's a bad idea use an event (click) to "listen" the change of input type check-box). NOTE: I'm not an expert in Angular, it's only my experience.